# No sound in speaker just headphone

Tags: sound, speakers

I have no sound on my speaker in ubuntu 20.04 (Acer) and there is just a headphone button.
How can i fix this problem ?
Tnx

Answer (score 0):

from settings --> SOUNDS

pull out your headphone if you left attached and then you can choice Headphone or internal speaker and then level your speaker sound.

In my laptop if you insert the headphone you can level only headphone volume, but if you plug out headphone you can level internal speaker volume

Comment: My headphone is unplug now but still show just the headphone button and its settings :(

Comment: uhmm very strange I'm using ubuntu 20.04 too, Have you opened the settings window ? where you have a lot of config possibilities and you can modify the option binded to  sounds ?

Comment: Yes ,  i did .i said it has just one button which is belong to headphone